# Set variables by using fgetc(stdin)

Tags: c, stdin, fgetc

I am trying to set variables by using `fgetc()` from `stdin`.

Here's my code so far,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int ch;
    int firstNumber,secondNumber;
    char str;

    printf("Enter two numbers and a string: ");
    while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){
        while(ch != ' '){
            firstNumber = ch;
            secondNumber = ch;
            string = ch;
            }
        }
    printf("%d %d %s",firstNumber,secondNumber,string);
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, if I type `2 2 string` (there's whitespace between characters)

I want variable `firstNumber` to be `2`

and `secondNumber` to be `2`

and `str` to be `string`

Comment: You are reading characters in ASCII. You must convert the characters to numbers. Try `firstNumber = atoi(ch);` You are reading characters one-at-a-time, so this won't work for multi-digit numbers.

Comment: `scanf` is more appropriate for your task.

Comment: while(ch != '  ') condition will goes to infinite loop ,if you give a non-space charecter  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible approach:

> 1. You can parse the entire string first and store it into temporary buffer.
> 2. You can now use `strtok()` to tokenize the string using `' '(space)`  character. Alternatively, you can use `sscanf()` instead of `strtok()`.
> 3. Use `atoi()` for first two numbers and read the final string.

**Code**:

> Assuming that the buffer required to store scanned string doesn't exceed `100` bytes.

**Approach using `strtok()`:**

```
int main()
{
    int ch,i=0;
    int firstNumber,secondNumber;
    const char seperator[2] = " -";
    char buffer[100];
    char *string;

    printf("Enter two numbers and a string: ");
    while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){
        buff[i++]=ch;
    }

    /* get the first token as a number */
    firstNumber = atoi(strtok(buff, seperator));
    printf("%d\n",firstNumber);

    /* get the second token as a number*/   
    secondNumber = atoi(strtok(NULL, seperator));    
    printf("%d\n",secondNumber);

    /* get the third token as a string */
    string=strtok(NULL, seperator);
    printf("%s\n",string);

    return(0);
}
```

**Approach using `sscanf()`:**

```
printf("Enter two numbers and a string: ");
while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){
    buff[i++]=ch;
}

sscanf(buff, "%d %d %s", &firstNumber, &secondNumber, string);  
printf("%d\n%d\n%s\n", firstNumber, secondNumber, string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int ch;
    int firstNumber=0,secondNumber=0,b=0;
    char str;

    printf("Enter two numbers and a string: ");
    while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){
        if (ch != ' '){
            if (b==0)
                 firstNumber = firstnumber*10 + ch-'0';
            else
            if (b==1)
                secondNumber = secondnumber*10 + ch-'0';
            else
                str = ch;
        }
        else b++;
    }
    printf("%d %d %c",firstNumber,secondNumber,str);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `b` keeps track of what you have assigned and that to print str, whch is actually just one character, you need to use `%c`. Further, there isn't a variable `string` that you want to print, only a `str`.

Comment: [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) takes a nul-terminated string, passing a single integer is UB.

Comment: what if numbers are more than a digit ex:22 234? in that case ch-'0' fails

Comment: @TryinHard, single digits is what the OP asked. See it as a demonstration for him/her to learn the basics.

Comment: Hey, OP has mentioned "two numbers" and "not two digit numbers"

Comment: @TryinHard, fixed it. Only didn't fix string, which remains a single character that gets overwritten if there are more than one. Would require buffer of potentially unlimted size and won't go into that problem - leave something for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

No need of strtok, we can achieve the same here in sscanf;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
      int firstNumber,secondNumber;
      char str[100];
      char buffer[100];

      printf("Enter two numbers and a string: ");
      fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

      sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %s", &firstNumber, &secondNumber, str);
      printf("%d %d %s\n",firstNumber,secondNumber,str);

      return(0);
}
```

Output

```
root@viswesn-vm:/var/lib/lxc# ./a.out 

Enter two numbers and a string: 2 234 king

2 234 king
```